# REST API Design: Dependents resources

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have two resources: Customers and Users

Each customer can have multiple Users.
Users only exists within a Customer.

I have a page at the frontend that collects data from customer and user at the same time, to create de customer and its first user.

Example: Customer name, User password, User email

I want to create that customer and that user at the Rest API. How should I procced?

My first thought was:

```
POST /customer
body: {name: foo}
return {customer resource}
```

and then:

```
POST /customer/{id}/user
{email: user@email.com, password: secret}
return {user resource}
```

But if the user's creation fail I would have to delete the customer. But while the request to create the user is in progress the end-user could close de browser and I would have a lost customer created without user.

My second idea was create and account endpoint, who is not a resource in the database, and:

```
POST /account
{customer_name: foo, user_email: user@email.com, user_password: secret}
return {user resource}
```

Any of it makes sense? Other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create that customer and that user at the Rest API. How should I procced?

Think about how you would do it on the web.

You would probably have some sort of sign up page, a resource that would include a representation of a form.  The input controls of the form would describe to the visitor the information desired.  When the visitor clicks the submit button, and browser produces an HTTP request consistent with HTML's form processing server, and dispatches that request back to the server.  The server reads the information out of the message payload, does it's work, and sends back to the client another web page with status, additional information, links to other interesting resources, and so on.

For a part of the interaction protocol that is *unsafe* (meaning, the semantics of the request are not effectively read only), as "sign up" probably is, the form would specify that the POST method token be used in the request-line of the HTTP request.

That target URI can be anything - the browser is just going to copy whatever form.action is specified by the server.

```
POST /c4b809c9-2106-4664-8149-5d1817ca4e4b
```

would be a perfectly fine choice (though it might disappoint operators who are trying to figure out what is going on by reviewing HTTP logs).

Frequently, for messages that begin an interesting process (like an initial signup) use resource identifiers with collection semantics.  So this might be more familiar

```
POST /signups
```

You can create additional resources (yes, more than one) in the handling of a POST request; so your signups POST handler could create resources for the customer and the user.

Each of these resources would have its own URI.

```
/companies/1
/users/3
```

That would be fine.  Mechanically, there can be an advantage to using a common stem for both.  Again, the semantic hints in the logs may help the operators in their investigations.  Also, if two URI have the same root, you can use dot segments, to reference one resource from the other in a more general way

```
<base href="/companies/1/users/3">
<a href="./4">/companies/1/users/4</a>
<img src="../images/logo.gif" alt="/companies/1/images/logo.gif">
```